# How can I troubleshoot this SQL Server Proxy Error?

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2016.

I have a SQL Agent Job that uses powershell to restart MSMQ services on another computer, using an App Pool on that computer.

I set up a proxy account, using a domain account that has Admin privileges on the remote computer using these steps : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-sql-server-agent-proxy?view=sql-server-ver15

However, whenever I try to run that job it fails at the powershell step with :

```
Message
Executed as user: domain\adminuser. The process could not be created for step 1 of job 0x5BD3C80655ACF4408C8F8BF16BB164DF (reason: A required privilege is not held by the client).  The step failed.
```

I read that updating the local security on the remote computer and adding the domain account to "Replace a process level token" might help...but it seems to be against best practices.

I've also reached out to a DBA and an AD administrator but they need more evidence that something is wrong with *their* application before they do anything about it.

Comment: What privileges does that user have on the local server?  LogOnLocally?  LogOnAsAService?

Comment: I believe they do.  I can log onto the box as the domain account, and we currently use it as an application service account to run the application even if no one is logged in.